# iphone three20 based app show unexpected localized text when running on device

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization, three20, device

I have set the following setting in my app's -info.plist file, but still when running on the real device, I am seeing the localized string instead of english. The app is based on three20, what could be wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<string>en-US</string>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en_US</string>
```

Please note that I don't see the problem on emulator. And also, my iPhone device has no other language set of international but just English, neither do I have a different keyboard setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's directly related to three20.

I had a few cases that I had to change the product name temporarily to cause xcode to refresh the localized assets. You can try that. Search for the product name in the project's build settings.